# Terminology: The largest prime power of $f_i \in \mathbb{P}^+$ that divides $x \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

Let $x = \pm f_1^{k_1} f_2^{k_2} \cdots f_n^{k_n}$ where $f_i \in \mathbb{P}^+$, $k_i \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $f_i \neq f_j \iff i \neq j$ for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$.

Let $1 \leq m \leq n$ so that $f_m$ is the $m^{th}$ prime factor of $x$ as per above. Since $f_m^{k_m}$ is the largest prime power of $f_m$ that divides $x$, does there exist a special term that we can use to refer to it to distinguish it from other powers of $f_m$ that divide $x$?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation

Comment: In the context of factorization in rings, one might also say that $f_i^{k_i}$ is the $f_i$-primary component of $x$, although more properly this is a statement about the ideals in the ring $\mathbb Z$ generated by these integers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_decomposition, see in particular the part right above “examples” under the heading “primary decomposition of an ideal”).

Answer (score 1):

$f^k \mathrel{\Vert}n$ is commonly used, which is \mathrel{\Vert} in LaTeX.

Comment: How would you pronounce this if reading aloud?

Comment: @MichaelLugo something along the lines of "the bigger power of $f$ which divides $n$ is $f^k$"

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242.)